# Read crontab from file (and not using CLI)

Tags: ubuntu, cron, dropbox

I´d like to use crontab remotely, just modifing a crontab file with cron scripts, but without access to CLI (I mean, I won´t have access by remote desktop, Team Viewer, etc.). I´d use Dropbox to syncronize that file.

Do you know any proposal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**My proposal (it works):**

Just add this script at the bottom of your crontab file:

```
* * * * * crontab < /home/mypc/Dropbox/scripts
```

After the first execution, the file called "scripts" will be the active one. Also, take into account that changes in that file will be executed in next execution (in this example, 1 minute after you save the file).